# How to track individual state in React.useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs

I have a case where there are multiple states. And I want to monitor each state separately without affecting each other.

```
React.useEffect(() => {

  // code only run when **firebase** state change
  addNotify();
  firebaseListening();

 // code only run when **status** state change
 console.log(status)
 return () => {
 removeFirebaseListening();
};}, [firebase,status]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use separate useEffects for each purpose:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

  // code only run when firebase state change
  addNotify();
  firebaseListening();
 //

return () => {
  removeFirebaseListening();
};}, [firebase]);

React.useEffect(() => {

 // code only run when status state change
 console.log(status)

};}, [status]);
```